# Managed code library to write/read cabinet (.cab) files

Tags: .net, api, cab

I am looking for a managed code library/API or samples that let me write and read cabinet (.cab) files. There is a CAB SDK here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310618 but the DLL that ships with it only supports native code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/CABCompressExtract.aspx) is a Code Project Article with c++ and .net versions.

Have Fun

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the platform Invoke in the CAB SDK? if you can it meens you can support native code.