# Simple example to add files to CAB archive

Tags: installation, cab

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361928/where-can-i-get-the-cabarc-utility) about replacement of CABARC utility.
Microsoft help is covering a lot of options in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb267310.aspx#microsoftmakecabusersguide).

I need simple example how to add 2 files to CAB using makecab.exe utility.

Something like this.

```
makeCAB.exe file1.dll file2.INF result.cab
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create Directive file CABMaker.ddf

   `;*** MAKECAB Directive file
   .Set Cabinet=on
   .Set Compress=on
   file1.dll

   file2.INF`
2. Run C:\WINDOWS\system32\makecab.exe /F CABMaker.ddf

Answer (score 1):

For another option that works well for those with basic Visual Studio and C# knowledge, try the approach in my answer to this question.  A summary of that approach follows.

[C#/.NET: Creating a CAB and adding files to it without an external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939639/c-net-creating-a-cab-and-adding-files-to-it-without-an-external-library)

First, you expand all the files in your CAB file to a folder.  Then you add your two files, file1.dll and file2.INF to that folder.  Then you run the CabMaker.exe program (Windows GUI),   available on GitHub here:  https://github.com/sapientcoder/CabMaker
I simply got the code from GitHub, opened it with Visual Studio (2019), and compiled and ran it inside Visual Studio.

When run, you get the GUI shown below.  Note that the CabMaker program is a front end GUI that builds a command line for the MakeCab program and then runs that command line.  IN the process, CabMaker creates the necessary DDF file for you as part of its operation.
See my linked answer for further details.

[image]

Comment: It's a good answer. It can be used when we have a lof of files to be placed into a cab archive.