# Convert large files to .cab beside EXE or MSI

Tags: c#, cab

I have searched but couldn't find anything for my problem.

I have 3 GB files like PDF and Word in a folder which contain sub-folders too.
I want to convert this folder only to CAB file beside the installation files as i want to change a value in a file to every device.
I have c# output which contain exe and dlls and text files beside the files' folder.
So, i want to pack exe and text and dll files to MSI or EXE and convert files' folder to CAB file beside it.
When user install the program it will unpack cab file to installation folder.

> Can I have cab file as well as MSI (so that cab file is not part of MSI) ? rest of the dlls go into MSI.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#/.NET: Creating a CAB and adding files to it without an external library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939639/c-net-creating-a-cab-and-adding-files-to-it-without-an-external-library)

Comment: No it isn't duplicate. I know how to create CAB file but i'm asking how link how link it with exe

Comment: I wish if there any answer